Existence of a Pre-Term in $\lambda$-Calculus where Substitution is Defined.
I am reading Lectures on the Curry-Howard Isomorphism by Sorensen and Urzyczyn, and I got stuck when trying to fill in the details of Lemma 1.2.12(2). Below is the statement of Lemma 1.2.12.
Lemma 1.2.12.

For all pre-terms $M,N$ and all variable $x$, there exists a pre-term $M'$ such that $M =_\alpha M'$ (i.e., $M$ is $\alpha$-equivalent to $M'$) and the substitution $M'[x := N]$ is defined.
For all pre-terms $M,N,P$ and all variables $x,y$, there exist $M',N'$ such that $M =_\alpha M'$, $N =_\alpha N'$, and the substitutions $M'[x := N']$ and $M'[x := N'][y := P]$ are defined.

The proof of Lemma 1.2.12(1) is a simple induction on $M$. However, Lemma 1.2.12(2) seems much more complicated. Sorensen and Urzyczyn claim that Lemma 1.2.12(2) can also be easily solved by a straightforward induction on $M$, but I do not see how this works for application.
Let us assume that $M = AB$, where $A,B$ are pre-terms. By the induction hypothesis on $A$, there exist $A',N_1'$ such that $A =_\alpha A'$, $N =_\alpha N_1'$, and the substitutions $A'[x := N_1']$ and $A'[x := N_1'][y := P]$ are defined. Similarly, by the induction hypothesis on $B$, there exist $B',N_2'$ such that $B =_\alpha A'$, $N =_\alpha N_2'$, and the substitutions $B'[x := N_2']$ and $B'[x := N_2'][y := P]$ are defined. If $N_1' = N_2'$, then we could define $M' = A'B'$ and $N' = N_1' = N_2'$, and we would be done. But it is clear that one can construct an example here where $N_1' \ne N_2'$.
What elements should we add to the proof to ensure that $N_1' = N_2'$, or more generally, what is the correct way to prove Lemma 1.2.12(2)?

What is the definition of a pre-term? What does it mean that "the substitution $M[N/x]$ is defined"?

An alternative solution goes as follows. Let $\mathcal V$ be the (infinite) set of all variables, and $V \subset \mathcal V$ a finite subset. Define $B_V(-)$ by induction on pre-terms:
$$\begin{aligned}
B_V(x) & := x \\
B_V(MN) & := B_V(M) B_V(N) \\
B_V(λx.M) & := λy.B_{V \cup \{y\}}(M[x \leftarrow y])
\end{aligned}$$
where, in the last case, $y$ is a fresh variable (i.e. it appears neither in $V$ nor in $M$), and the renaming $M[x \leftarrow y]$ is well-defined because $y$ is fresh — in particular it does not appear bound in $M$.
We have $M =_α B_V(M)$ and $V \cap \mathrm{bv}(B_V(M)) = \emptyset$. In particular, $B_{\mathrm{fv}(M)}(M)$ satisfies Barendregt's convention: it has disjoint sets of free and bound variables.
You can use this in your lemma, by setting $V := \mathrm{fv}(N) \cup \mathrm{fv}(P)$, and then $M' := B_V(M)$ and $N' := B_V(N)$.
You get:

$\mathrm{fv}(N') \cap \mathrm{bv}(M') = \emptyset$, so the substitution $M'[N'/x]$ is defined.
$\mathrm{fv}(P) \cap \mathrm{bv}(M'[N'/x]) \subseteq \mathrm{fv}(P) \cap (\mathrm{bv}(M') \cup \mathrm{bv}(M')) = \emptyset$, so the substitution $M'[N'/x][P/y]$ is defined.

This technique is more general than an ad hoc induction, because Barendregt's convention allows to define substitution in general (see Berendregt's book).
Yet another option is to use Krivine's definition of α-equivalence, which makes many things easier in the end. It seems weird at first, but in my opinion it is the most canonical definition (because it is tightly related to the abstract presentation of α-equivalence via nominal sets).

My attempt:
The problem with the initial attempt to prove Lemma 1.2.12(2) by direct induction on $M$ is obvious. When $M$ is an application, such as $AB$, applying the induction hypothesis to $A$ and $B$ respectively yields $N_1'$ and $N_2'$, which are $\alpha$ equivalent to $N$, but not necessarily identical. This prevents us from simply defining $M' = A'B'$ and $N' = N_1'$, since we need to define the same $N'$ for both substitutions involving $A'$ and $B'$.
A more robust approach involves induction on the structure of both $M$ and $N$. Rather than just proving the statement in the lemma, we strengthen it slightly to make the induction valid. The modified statement is:

For all predicates $M, N, P$ and all variables $x, y$, there exist $M', N'$ such that $M =_\alpha M'$, $N =_\alpha N'$, $x, y \notin \mathrm{FV}(P)$, and the substitutions $M'[x := N']$ and $M'[x := N'][y := P]$ are defined.

Adding the condition $x, y \notin \mathrm{FV}(P)$ does not weaken the statement we actually want to prove, and helps simplify some of the inductive cases.
The proof is by induction on $M$, while in each case induction on $N$.
The base case where $M$ is a variable is simple. We can always choose $M' = M$ and $N' = N$. The interesting part comes from the inductive case.
When $M = \lambda z. A$, we first use Lemma 1.2.12(1) to find an $A_1​​$ such that $A =_\alpha A_1$ and $A_1​​[z := P]$ is defined. We then apply the induction hypothesis to $A_1​​$ (with $N$ and $P$ as before) to obtain $A_2$ and $N_2$. Now we pick a new variable $z'$ outside of $\mathrm{FV}(A_2) \cup \mathrm{FV}(N_2) \cup \mathrm{FV}(P) \cup \{x, y\}$ and define $A' = A_2[z := z']$. We set $M' = \lambda z'. A'$ and $N' = N_2$. The choice of $z'$ ensures that $M =_\alpha M'$ and $N =_\alpha N'$. Moreover, since the freshness of $z'$ and the corresponding substitutions involving $A_2$ are defined, the substitutions $M'[x := N']$ and $M'[x := N'][y := P]$ are defined.
The key case is $M = AB$. Here, we first apply the induction hypothesis to $A$ (with $N$ and $P$) to obtain $A_1​​$ and $N_1$. Then, we apply the induction hypothesis to $B$ (with $N_1$ and $P$) to obtain $B'$ and $N'$. Finally, we apply the induction hypothesis again to $A_1​​$ (with $N'$ and $P$) to obtain $A'$ and $N_2'$. We set $M' = A'B'$. Since $N' =_\alpha N_2'$, and $B'[x:=N']$ and $B'[x := N'][y := P]$ are both defined, then $B'[x := N_2']$ and $B'[x := N_2'][y := P]$ are also defined.
By construction, $M =_\alpha M'$ and $N =_\alpha N_2'$. Crucially, because we apply the induction hypothesis to $B$ with $N_1$ and subsequently to $A_1​​$ with $N'$, we enforce that the second preterm obtained is $N_2'$ in both cases, thus ensuring compatibility. The substitutions $M'[x := N_2']$ and $M'[x := N_2'][y := P]$ are well-defined because they decompose into substitutions involving $A'$ and $B'$, as defined by the induction hypothesis.
Performing simultaneous induction on $M$ and $N$ ensures that the $N'$ chosen at each step is compatible with the previous choice, thus resolving a problem encountered in simpler inductive methods. Thus, we have proved a stronger statement that implies the desired result.
